# How @selector affects program flow in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am new to the iOS programming and now I write an App which have to connect to SOAP WS. I used soft from the Internet (SudzC) to generate enveloping class for the WS. To receive response from the service it uses `@selector` which passes execution to response handler routine. I though that when program flow goes to handler routine of the response it will go back to the initial routine (after finishing its job), but for my surprise I found that calling routine is finished and after that handler routine is invoked. May be I don't understand iOS program flow correctly!

Is there a descent explanation about program flow where @selector is involved?

**EDIT:**
Here is sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    WS* service = [WS service];
    service.logging = YES;

    [service WS_Method:self action:@selector(WS_MethodHandler:) iParam1: 1 sParam2: @"string" iParam3: 1];

    NSLog(@"!!! Finish !!!");
}

- (void) WS_MethodHandler: (id) value {

    // Handle errors
    if([value isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    // Handle faults
    if([value isKindOfClass:[SoapFault class]]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", value);
        return;
    }

    WS_CheckIussue* result = (WS_CheckIussue*)value;
    NSLog(@"WS_CheckIussue returned the value: %@", result);
 NSLog(@"!!! Finish !!! 2");
}
```

As a result I have !!! Finish !!! and after that !!! Finish !!! 2

Comment: -1 because you didn't post any code.

Comment: I did not post any code, because I think that is some general behaviour. I edit my question.

Comment: @SevenBits You are not *required* to post code in a question or an answer.  +1 to compensate.

Comment: Actually I have to say 10x to @SevenBits, at least he explain why he is set -1. In that way I can not repeat my mistake when next time I make something wrong when I ask a question.

Comment: 10x also to you @Droppy, because I am almost bellow 15 and I can not vote up :)

Comment: @Droppy But in this circumstance, we cannot help all that well without code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network code is usually run on a separate thread. So I'm going to assume your code looks something like this:

```
- (void)downloadData
{
    //Step 1 : Request data from webservice
    WebServiceDohickey * webservice = [[WebServiceDohickey alloc] init];
    //This will run on a separate thread. 
    //The selector passed in may be performed during or after any other code in this method
    [webservice getWebServiceResponseWithCallback:@selector(responseHandler:)
                                           target:self];

    //Step 3 : Invalid program flow area
    //I'm guessing you have more code here that you expect to happen after the code in your responseHandler, but it actually executes before. That code should be in the responseHandler method
}
- (void)responseHandler:(WebServiceResponse *)response
{
    //Step 2 : Handle response object

    //Step 3 : This is where step 3 should live

    //Side note : Your callback may need to specifically be put on a specific thread.
    //Wrap step 2 and 3 in a block like this to put it on the main thread which is common for UI code execution.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, my problem is because I use network code and it runs in separate thread.